# PHP - Add Values when Update

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I add the values when I update the value? like for example everytime I update the value it is incrementing or adding?

**Current Output** - My current output is i am updating the value but everytime i update the value it is just changing the value not adding it. like for example i update the value `1000` and it will change to `1000` and after i update the value again to `200` the value will change to `200` BUT it should be `1200`

**Problem** -My problem is i cannot add the values everytime i update the value

**Expected Output** - I need to add or make it an increment everytime i update the value

here is my code and database update query statement

```
  <?php

  //CONNECTION
  $connection =mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
  $db = mysqli_select_db($connection,'inflightapp');

  //END CONNECTION

  //SUBMIT THE INPUT AND SEARCH THE LIKE VALUE
  if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $txtCode = $_POST['id'];
  //GET THE INPUT BELOW AMOUNT

  //REMOVE THE SPECIAL CHARACTER QR CODE: | TO READ AND SEARCH FOR SIMILAR VALUE
  $hashCase =  $txtCode;
  $str = ltrim( strstr($hashCase,":"),":");
  $strFinalString = trim(substr($str,0,strpos($str, "|")));
  //END OF REMOVING SPECIAL CHAR


  //QUERY TO SEARCH THE VALUE
  $query = "SELECT * FROM scratch_cards WHERE code LIKE '%$strFinalString%' ";
  $query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
  //END

  //FETCH THE DATA INTO MY DATABASE 'scratch_cards'
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run))
  {
   $txtValue = $row['amount'];
  ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="amount[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['amount'] ?>">
      <h2><i><u>You have received: <?php echo '<b style="color:#90EE90">'.$row['amount'].'</b>'  ?> Coins</u></i></h2>
  <?php



    //QUERY TO UPDATE THE VALUE
  $query2 = "UPDATE shopusers SET ewallet = '$txtValue' WHERE id = 12";
  $query_run2 = mysqli_query($connection,$query2);
  //END
  }

   //END OF FETCHING DATA
  }

  ?>
```

and here is the button which will trigger to update the value

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" name="mywallet" class="btn btn-primary" value="Top-up"></input>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query2 = "UPDATE shopusers SET ewallet = ewallet + " . (0 + $txtValue) . " WHERE id = 12";
```

Actually, a better way to write this would be:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE shopusers SET ewallet = ewallet + ? WHERE id = 12");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $txtValue);
$stmt->execute();
```

What I gave you previously should work, but you should probably use prepare for everything to make sure the data you are passing to the database is in the proper format.  To prevent sql injection.

[mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: what does 0 means sir?

Comment: `.(0 + $txtValue)` what does this means?

Comment: Well it is making sure it is a number.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is

```
//QUERY TO UPDATE THE VALUE

$query2 = "UPDATE shopusers SET ewallet = ewallet + '$txtValue' WHERE id = 12";
```

Comment: hello what changes your code will execute? it just looks like mine i think it will not work

Comment: this would update the column with previous value+ current variable value

Answer (score -1):

This update query you must try..

```
$query2 = "UPDATE shopusers SET ewallet = ewallet+'$txtValue' WHERE id = 12";
```

this might you help you out most